# Missing type for identifier in case statement

Tags: scheme, racket, typed-racket

I'm trying to learn typed racket and I'm running into some type annotation issues.

```
#lang typed/racket
(require typed/racket/gui)

(define frame (new frame% [label "test frame"]))



(define tab-panel (new tab-panel% [parent frame] [choices '("One" "Two" "Three")]
                       [min-height 300] [min-width 300]
                       (callback
                               (lambda (tp e)
                                (case (send tp get-selection)
                                 ((0) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list a-panel))))
                                 ((1) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list b-panel))))
                                 ((2) (send tp change-children (lambda (children) (list c-panel)))))))))

(define a-panel (new panel% (parent tab-panel)))
(define a-text (new message% (parent a-panel) (label "A-panel")))
(define b-panel (new panel% (parent tab-panel)))
(define b-text (new message% (parent b-panel) (label "B-panel")))
(define c-panel (new panel% (parent tab-panel)))
(define c-text (new message% (parent c-panel) (label "C-panel")))
```

Generates the following errors on the lines in the case statement:

```
. Type Checker: missing type for identifier;
 consider adding a type annotation with `:'
  identifier: a-panel in: a-panel
. Type Checker: missing type for identifier;
 consider adding a type annotation with `:'
  identifier: b-panel in: b-panel
. Type Checker: missing type for identifier;
 consider adding a type annotation with `:'
  identifier: c-panel in: c-panel
. Type Checker: Summary: 3 errors encountered in:
  a-panel
  b-panel
  c-panel
```

I've been digging through the documentation and I cannot seem to figure out the correct syntax for the type declaration to fix this issue.

This is not homework. I'm just trying to learn typed racket because I think strong typing is a good idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `case` statement and GUI stuff obfuscate the problem. Sometimes it can be easier to figure out what's wrong by trying out smaller examples. Here the problem is the same as the problem in this much simpler program:

```
#lang typed/racket

(define (list-abc)
  (list a b c))

(define a 1)
(define b 2)
(define c 3)
```

It has to know the types of `a`, `b`, and `c` in order to infer the type of `list-abc`. There are two ways to solve this. Either put a type annotation on `list-abc`, or put type annotations on `a`, `b`, and `c`.

Either:

```
(: list-abc : -> (Listof Integer))
(define (list-abc)
  (list a b c))
```

Or:

```
(define a : Integer 1)
(define b : Integer 2)
(define c : Integer 3)
```

This solution to the simpler problem also translates to your larger program. You can solve it either with a type annotation on `tab-panel`, or with type annotations on `a-panel`, `b-panel`, and `c-panel`.

For your program, the annotations wouldn't be `(-> (Listof Integer))` and `Integer`, they would be `(Instance Tab-Panel%)` and `(Instance Panel%)`.

Comment: When I try to add annotations in the defines for the panels, I receive a different error that makes no sense : Type Checker: parse error in type;
 type name 'panel%' is unbound in: panel%
<br> I know what it means, but it makes no sense that the error is happening. `panel%` is defined in typed/racket/gui

Comment: Okay. The type for objects is `(Instance Class-Type)` where `Class-Type` is the type of the class. The type of `panel%` is `Panel%`, so the type for an object of that is `(Instance Panel%)`. This is described in the [documentation for typed classes](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-reference/Typed_Classes.html#%28form._%28%28lib._typed-racket%2Fbase-env%2Fbase-types-extra..rkt%29._.Instance%29%29).

Comment: That did it! Thank you. I've been doing OO programming for decades but I'm very new to Typed Racket. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay. I can see why you thought the type would just be the class name. Typed Racket classes aren't directly used as types because they are first-class values. Instead they have `(Instance ...)` to distinguish object types from class types.